# Corona SDK, speed up sounds

Tags: performance, audio, lua, coronasdk

How can I speed up sound using Corona? I need to build up function which must sets up pace for melody(contains some different sound files which plays back in a row)

Answer (score 0):

To change the speed of the sounds you play, you have to change their pitch.

```
local channel, source = audio.play(soundName, possibleSettings)
al.Source(source, al.PITCH, pitchDesired)
```

You can find more about the 'secret undocumented apis' here:
https://coronalabs.com/blog/2011/07/27/the-secretundocumented-audio-apis-in-corona-sdk/

Comment: I need to speed up sounds

Comment: Thanks a lot but your link is unavailable

Comment: sorry @brun0 they must have removed it. You will see even this year a lot of results in google which reference this address. so, you can use my code. Pitch desired is provided as a float value as percentage, so 0-1 is 0-100%, if you want 200% that will be 2.0

Comment: Do you know something about speed up sounds without changing pitch?